# get div width, when he do not set

Tags: jquery

How do I get a div element width, if it do not set?

```
<div class="test">Text text</div> 
alert($('.test').width()); - now i get my all page width, but not div width.
```

Comment: `now i get my all page width, but not div width.` - um... sounds about right? The div will automatically adopt the page's width, no?

Comment: You are not setting width of the page. Are you using float ?

Comment: The jQuery is code is OK. Check if you have the class 'test' somewhere else in you html. Also, please provide the surrounding html. You don't have to explicitly set the width of a div. Depending on the html you have the div will have it's width set accordingly (maybe the div gets the width of the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since divs are by default blocks, it inherits it's parents 100% width,

therefore: your div Test would have to be 100% of your parent and the value you get alerted is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What class="test"?

If you haven't set the div width there the div will be as width as the page is.

Answer (score 0):

The default width for page is taken in this problem(parent width).Use numeric width for test.This will display perfect width.

Answer (score 0):

you should try using `span` instead of `div` in your case, coz div will take 100% of parents width